# #load a package in F# interactive (FSharpChart.fsx)

Tags: f#, load, package, interactive

Hi i'm a noob and asking this newbie question, please forgive me.

I've installed successfully FSharpChart in my local directory

```
...
Added package 'MSDN.FSharpChart.dll.0.60.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Expert in F\packages'
Added package 'MSDN.FSharpChart.dll.0.60.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'MSDN.FSharpChart.dll 0.60.0' to Expert in F
```

now, if i do

```
#load "FSharpChart.fsx";;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(4,1): error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'FSharpChart.fsx' in any of
 C:\Users\Fagui\AppData\Local\Temp
```

additional info:
[image: directory]

inside this folder, i see a nupkg file, and a lib directory
Inside the lib directory, there is a dll, and a pdf file, 
but i don't see any .fsx file.

basically, F# has installed the package in the active folder for the current project, and F#interactive is in another folder ?? bit strange ?

should i install another time the package ? or what is the way around it ?

thanks

**UPDATE:**
i don't know why, but apparently when i installed the FSharpChart package, I only got the dll, no fsx file
i managed to load it doing

```
#I @"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Expert in F"
#r @"packages\MSDN.FSharpChart.dll.0.60\lib\MSDN.FSharpChart.dll";;
```

unfortunately, typing the script in F# interactive

```
open MSDN.FSharp.Charting
let rnd = System.Random()
let rand() = rnd.NextDouble()
let randomPoints = [for i in 0 .. 1000 -> 10.0 * rand(), 10.0 * rand()]
randomPoints |> FSharpChart.Point;;
```

doesn't yield any chart, but just returns a list

```
val rnd : Random
val rand : unit -> float
val randomPoints : (float * float) list =
  [(9.765916457, 2.272289941); (0.8211438594, 1.625466995);
   ...
   (7.783786034, 7.572208311); (6.497914692, 3.66987128); ...]
val it : ChartTypes.PointChart
```

this may be due to the fact that the library is not supported anymore, and that i should use a newer library like Thomas Petricek indicated.

So, i did manage to install FSharp.Charting instead

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let rand() = rnd.NextDouble()
let randomPoints = [for i in 0 .. 1000 -> 10.0 * rand(), 10.0 * rand()]
randomPoints |> Chart.Point;;
```

and it did work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a newer version of the `FSharpChart.fsx` library which is called [F# Charting](http://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/ReferencingTheLibrary.html), so first of all, I would recommend using this newer library instead (the API is quite similar, but F# Charting has a number of improvements).

The documentation for F# Charting also has a [detailed page on referencing the library](http://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/ReferencingTheLibrary.html).

Typically, when you reference the library using NuGet, you'll need to specify relative reference:

```
// On Mac OSX use packages/FSharp.Charting.Gtk.0.90.13/FSharp.Charting.Gtk.fsx
#load "packages/FSharp.Charting.0.90.13/FSharp.Charting.fsx"
```

Where `0.90.13` is the version of the library that you got from NuGet (you may need to check the folder name - the path references in `#load` are relative to the place where your script lives).

Comment: thanks for your answer and telling me about the new library. for the time being, its more to reproduce the code of the book Expert in F than trying to use this package. I still don't manage to load the library in F#, i don't know how to setup the right path

Answer (score 2):

Yes, F# Interactive is independent of the current project.

Use:

```
#load @"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Expert in F\packages\FSharpChart.fsx";;
```

Also you can use the `#I` directive if you need to reference assemblies of a specific folder, [see the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx).

Comment: in F# interactive if i type `Environment.CurrentDirectory;;` i see `val it : string = "C:\Users\Fagui\AppData\Local\Temp"`. Then, typing your line gives me the following `> stdin(4,1): error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Expert in F\packagesFSharpChart.fsx' in any of
 C:\Users\Fagui\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: @FaguiCurtain Sorry, there was a bar missing, see the update.