# Load dotnet project files in F# Interactive

Tags: .net, f#

I have a F# dotnet project with some dependencies in my `.fsproj` (e.g. `<PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.0.0-beta4" />`).

Now I want to test some functions in a module I wrote, so I start `fsharpi` and try to load my module with `#load "Program.fs";;`.

However, then I get `error FS0039: The type 'CsvProvider' is not defined`.

How can I load my module with the correct dependencies?

I have seen workarounds which include manually loading all required `dll`s from some obscure system dependent path (e.g. [#load a package in F# interactive (FSharpChart.fsx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482491/load-a-package-in-f-interactive-fsharpchart-fsx)), but I guess there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few option for doing this, none of them perfect.

### Ionide

If you are using Ionide, then you can right click on a project in F# view and choose "Generate References for FSI". This will create an F# script that loads all of the dependencies and project files for you. Write your test code below this.

The downsides of this approach:

- You will need to run the procedure every time the project files or dependencies change.
- Not applicable where you don't have access to VS Code, although you might check these scripts into source-control.

### Paket

If you are using Paket, then you can generate "load scripts" for your project:

```sh
dotnet paket generate-load-scripts
```

This will generate F# scripts in `./.paket/load`. There will be a load script for each dependency (and its transitive dependencies) and for each Paket "group".

This can automatically sync with your `paket.dependencies` if you add this line:

```
generate_load_scripts: true
```

See: https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-generate-load-scripts.html

The downsides of this approach:

- It may load more dependencies than you actually need, which has a performance cost
- You must `#load` you project files manually

### Dotnet + Nuget

New with .NET 5, you can write Nuget strings directly in your `fsx` files. This is a great feature for quick scripts!

```ml
#r "nuget: FParsec"

// Package with a specific version
// #r "nuget: FParsec,1.1.1"

open FParsec

#load "./Types.fs"

// etc...
```

The downsides of this approach:

- It does not sync package versions with Paket, if you are using that for your project code
- You must `#load` you project files manually

### One Day?

In an ideal world, we would be able to do something like this:

```ml
#r "fsproj: ./my-proj.fsproj"

open FParsec

// etc...
```

There is an issue for this here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8764

Answer (score 4):

In order to get access to the code in imported libraries, you need to tell the FSI to load them.

At the lowest level, this can be done with an `#r` directive:

```
#r "./packages/FSharp.Data/lib/whatever/FSharp.Data.dll"
```

This is often sufficient for one-off purposes.

However, if there are a lot of references, your IDE can usually automate this for you. For example, in Visual Studio, you can right-click the project and select either "Send References to F# Interactive" or "Generate Script File with References" (not sure about the exact wording). The same options are available in VSCode if you have the Ionide extension installed.

Also, there is an active proposal+prototype for supporting packages in FSI directly - see https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/542. However, that is not yet merged and seems to have stalled a bit.

Comment: Thanks. The Ionide feature "Generate Script File with References" is a step in the right direction. However, when I try to load it I get another error `error FS0193: The module/namespace 'System' from compilation unit 'System.Runtime' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'ReadOnlySpan1'`. Maybe my `fsharpi` version is not compatible with the target framework I configured in the project. If I change it from `netcoreapp2.1` to `net472` I get the error `error MSB3644: The reference assembliesfor framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" were not found.` when trying to build the project.

Comment: Also: is there a commandline tool to generate the project references or is this only available in some IDEs?

Comment: @peq If you switch to Paket, there’s https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-generate-load-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comments on Fyodor's answer, here's a script that I've used in the past to generate the `#r` and `#load` directives required to load an `.fsproj` in F# Interactive:

```
module References

#r "System.Xml"
#r "System.Xml.Linq"

open System
open System.IO
open System.Linq
open System.Xml.Linq

let inline isNotNull o = o |> isNull |> not

let private getProject path =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*proj") |> Seq.head |> XDocument.Load    

let generateDlls path =
    let projectFile = getProject path
    let references =
        projectFile.Descendants <| XName.Get("HintPath", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
        |> Seq.filter (fun reference -> reference.Value.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
        |> Seq.filter (fun reference -> reference.Value.StartsWith("$") |> not)
        |> Seq.map (fun reference -> reference.Value)
    let projects =
        projectFile.Descendants <| XName.Get("ProjectReference", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
        |> Seq.map (fun reference -> reference.Elements(XName.Get("Name", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")).SingleOrDefault())
        |> Seq.filter (fun nameElement -> nameElement |> isNotNull)
        |> Seq.map (fun nameElement -> nameElement.Value)
        |> Seq.map (fun reference -> sprintf "../%s/bin/debug/%s.dll" reference reference)

    references 
    |> Seq.append projects
    |> Seq.iter (fun reference -> printfn "#r @\"%s\"" reference)

let generateFs path =
    let projectFile = getProject path
    projectFile.Descendants <| XName.Get("Compile", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")
    |> Seq.map (fun reference -> reference.Attribute("Include" |> XName.op_Implicit))
    |> Seq.filter (fun reference -> reference |> isNotNull && reference.Value.ToLower().EndsWith("fs"))
    |> Seq.filter (fun reference -> reference.Value.Equals("AssemblyInfo.fs", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) |> not)
    |> Seq.iter (fun reference -> printfn "#load @\"%s\"" reference.Value)


// Example Usage:
// #load @"GenerateReferences.fsx"
// References.generateDlls __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
// References.generateFs __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
```

I'm not sure this is completely perfect, for instance, I don't think it gets dependency-ordering right.  However, it should be a reasonable starting point if you want to enhance it.